# VectorScriptで他のファイルからハンドルを読み込む

Tags: python, python3, vectorworks

VectorWorks2018のVectorScriptに関してですが
現在開いているファイルとは別のファイルの図形（ハンドル）の情報を取得したいと考えております。

具体的には複数のvwxファイルを同じフォルダに集めてプラグインを実行すると
ファイル内の特定の図形の情報が取得できるといった感じです。

最初はBuildResourceListN()で可能かとも思ったのですが、どうも無理なようです。

もし知っている方がいらっしゃいましたらご回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 私は今Vectorworksを知ったのですが、VectorworksではPascal風言語のVectorScriptを使ってスクリプトを書く方法と、Pythonを使ってスクリプトを書く方法のふたつがあるようです。最初付いていたタグから判断するに、後者（Python）をお使いだということでよろしいでしょうか？ http://developer.vectorworks.net/index.php/Vectorworks_Scripting

Comment: はい、そうです。ただ、APIは共通しているようなので、どちらでPascalでできてPythonでできないということはないと思います

Comment: 試してみて動かなかったソースコードや、動かなかったときの挙動（○○というエラーが出たとか、ログは無いものの想定通り動かなかったなど）を追記して頂くことは可能でしょうか？　原因の切り分けがしたいです。回答者がイチからコードを書いて回答にするよりかは既に幾らか書かれているコードを修正して回答にするほうが簡単なので、回答が集まりやすくなるというメリットもあります。可能であれば、質問文下の「編集」から追記して頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: また、Vectorworksを動かしている環境はWindows 10でしょうか、それ以外のものでしょうか？　このあたりも追記して頂けると助かります。